# mysql nested subqueries with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. I want to be able to get the orders of each id in the credit table from the orders table code below:

```
$downlinequery = "SELECT recid, Level, sp1 FROM credit 
                  WHERE sp1 = '$id' or sp2 = '$id' or sp3 = '$id' or sp4 = '$id' 
                  or sp5 = '$id' or sp6 = '$id' or sp7 = '$id' or sp8 = '$id'" ; 
$downlineresult = mysql_query($downlinequery) ;
while ($downlinerow = mysql_fetch_array($downlineresult)) {
  extract($downlinerow) ;
  $orderquery = "SELECT date,cc,cop FROM order WHERE userid='1127'" ;
  $orderresult = mysql_query($orderquery) or die("unable to get orders");
  while($orderrow = mysql_fetch_array($orderresult)){
    extract($orderrow);
    echo "$date,$cc,$cop" ;
  }
}
```

but i keep getting the error: unable to get orders

Is it possible to make queries while another is running ?

Comment: where you are getting error and please specify error. This will help me to give you best answer

Answer (score 2):

The error might happend because "ORDER" is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You should escape it with backticks:

```
$orderquery = "SELECT date,cc,cop FROM `order` WHERE userid=1127" ;
```

Same should be for "date", although that's being tolerated (see further down in the same page I linked)

As for your question, of course you can do queries in a loop (although that's not really the best in terms of performance). But if your tables have a foreing key (I'm guessing 'recid' and 'userid') you can build a JOINed query instead

Comment: Good find, also he should change the name of the table all together. General rule is not to use reserved words for variables.

Answer (score 1):

To your actual question:
I don't think the question is right. The first query is not running. It ran and it filled result in $downlineresult (mysql_query) and then, you are just iterating thru the parts of the result (mysql_fetch_array).

It seems you have error in your MySQL query, so you should use:

```
echo mysql_error();
```

See the description of the methods you use:

- [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
- [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)